# What's wrong with my VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel

Please help me understand the source of my code's error:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim MyRange as double
    Dim ErrorCheck as Boolean
    Set MyRange = Sheets(1)
    ErrorCheck = WorksheetFunction.IsError(MyRange)
    If ErrorCheck = True Then MsgBox "ERROR on the Sheet"
End Sub
```

Comment: What is error? Please paste the error

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: What is WorksheetFunction?

Comment: You have declared `MyRange` as a `Double` and then tried to set to it a `Sheet`.

Comment: @AshReva: `WorksheetFunction` allows you to use garden-variety Excel functions in VBA. More here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/callingworksheetfunctionsinvba.aspx

Comment: What error message are you getting?  What have you tried to correct it?  When writing a question show some effort that you have researched it and tried to fix it before asking for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Set MyRange = Sheets(1)
```

This tries to create a worksheet object called MyRange, NOT a range object.(and as A Webb points out you have DIM MyRange as double
Also if you are trying to check whether 1 or more cells on Sheets(1) contains an error you cannot use IsError on a range of cells to detect if any of the range contains an error.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I think I understand my error now. Is there any way to check for an error on the whole worksheet (or a workbook, if that permits)?